# Querystring in Parity Dapp frontend

Tags: dapp-development, dapps, parity

I'm playing with local Dapp for Parity.

When I'm trying to use query string in Dapp, I can't get it with js:

[image]

I see that iframe is used inside, but have no idea, how to add query string there.

Is any way to use query strings in Dapps for Parity to enable different logic of Dapp based on this query?